# How can I load a model with assimp.net and C# when my current code isn't working?

Tags: c#, assimp

I'm trying to import a model with assimp.net and c# but the my code doesn't work any help?

Here is my code:

```
 public void LoadModel(string model, out float[] vertices, out int[] indices) {       
        AssimpContext contex = new AssimpContext();
        var a = contex.ImportFile(model);
        Mesh[] meshes;

        int vnumber = 0;

        calcMeshes(a,out meshes);

        calcVerices(meshes[0], vnumber, out vertices);

        calcIndices(meshes[0],out indices);

    }

    void calcMeshes(Scene scenes,out Mesh[] a)
    {

        a = scenes.Meshes.ToArray();

    }
    void calcIndices(Mesh mesh, out int[] a)
    {

        a = mesh.GetIndices();
        
    }

    void calcVerices(Mesh mesh,int vnumber, out float[] a)
    {

        List<float> v = new List<float>();
        foreach (var item in mesh.Vertices)
        {

            v.Add(item.X);
            v.Add(item.Y);
            v.Add(item.Z);
            v.Add(mesh.TextureCoordinateChannels[0][vnumber].X);
            v.Add(mesh.TextureCoordinateChannels[0][vnumber].Y);
            vnumber += 1;

        }

        a = v.ToArray();

    }`
```

I tried to rewrite the function and the result is this the result (should be a cube):[image]

I don't know if is an indices issuse or a veritces issues.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looks like a index issue. Unfortunately, you havent't shown the code for creating the indices as well. All render data in assimp is separated into vertex- and index data. The indices will describe which face with the related vertices shall be used. And this information was ignored in your code if I have understood it correctly.